# how to keep scroll on modal popup called from an other modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

here my problem: 
I open a modal popup and I can scroll it properly, then when I open a new model popup from this one if I try to scroll down this popup the scroll is on the main webpage in background. How can I focus the scroll on the active modal popup?

thank you

Comment: Found the solution by myself: $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $('body').addClass('modal-open');
   });

Comment: because: when you open a modal, exist one class named "modal-open" on the first modal. When you close the sencond one, that class is going to delete. Just you have to program "close button" on the second modal with javascript.

when you click on Close or Cancel-> $('{modal}').addClass('modal-open);